# How to read helm environment specific variables (replaced by octopus) in nodejs application

Tags: kubernetes-helm, octopus-deploy

I have nodejs application deployed in Octopus using helm.
I want to read appVersion value in '.yaml file' that is replaced by octopus.
How can I read that in nodejs application

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but I solved it using a shell script and parsing the line I needed.

As the order of lines in YAML is irrelevant, I put the the `appVersion` line at last, then used the code below to get the version.

`tail -n 1 helm/pfweb/Chart.yaml | awk '{print $2}'`

You could run this code inside Node code using [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process)

Or you can read file from Node using [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) and parse which line you want. IMHO, this is more painful way to solve it, because I don't program in Node.